# How to run background Task in IOS using Xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have written code for background task functionality. But unable to hit the `PerformFetch` method.

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(MINIMUM_BACKGROUND_FETCH_INTERVAL);

LoadApplication(new App());

return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hello, new member!  I'm a question reviewer.  Your question is a bit thin on details and therefore not easy to answer.  Your code example is improperly formatted, and does not show the point at which you call PerformFetch.  Please give 1) a self-explanatory code example 2)  describe what you expect to see 3) describe what you actually.  You should review the help text [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)